# Custom jQuery Dropdown Navigation nested focus issue

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Why is it that when creating a bespoke jQuery script I always have one issue that holds me back!

Anyway enough ranting, I am reaching out to you all in the hope one kind soul can show me what I am doing incorrectly.

### The Issue

I have created a drop-down jQuery navigation menu for a site, only the menu thinks the mouse is leaving the 'target' when I try and move the cursor from the parent to the nested child and runs a 'hide()' function which makes the drop-down menu disappear.

What I need is for the .dropnav element (drop-down menu) to not trigger the '$target.on('mouseover', function(e) {' part of the code when the above scenario occurs.

Really stuck so any help what-so-ever is greatly appreciated.

### jQuery Code

```
var hover, $this;

        $target = $("header nav > ul > li");
        $menu = $target.find('.dropnav');


        $target.on('mouseover', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            clearTimeout(hover);

            $this = $(this)
            $this.toggleClass('active');

            hide();

            hover = setTimeout(show,400);

        }).mouseout(function() {
            clearTimeout(hover);
            hover = setTimeout(hide,800);
        });

        if($(".dropnav:visible")) {
            $menu.click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
            $(document).click(function() { hide(); });
        }

        function show() {
            $this.children('.dropnav').slideDown(800);
        }

        function hide() {
            $('.dropnav:visible').fadeOut(200);
        }
```

### HTML Code

```
<header>
<div id="nav-filler"></div>
<div id="header-inner">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="products" title="Browse our products">Products</a>
                <div class="dropnav">
                    <div id="dropnav-filler"></div>
                    <div id="dropnav-inner">
                        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropnav-links">
                            <li>
                                <h6>Desktops</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-one" title="Broadleaf">PC One</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-access" title="Broadleaf">PC Access</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-max" title="Broadleaf">PC Max</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc" title="Flex">PC</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/all-in-one" title="All In One">All In One</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <h6>Workstations</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/pcx" title="Broadleaf X">PC X</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-rhino" title="D4 Rhino">D4 Rhino</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-3ds" title="D4 3DS">D4 3DS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-inventor" title="D4 Inventor">D4 Inventor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/rackstation" title="Rackstation">Rackstations</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h6>On The Go</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/laptops" title="Laptop">Laptops</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/tablets" title="Tablet">Tablets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/ultrabooks" title="Ultrabook">Ultrabooks</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="showcase">
                            <div id="sc-inner"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="products" title="Browse our products">Other Products</a>
                <div class="dropnav">
                    <div id="dropnav-filler"></div>
                    <div id="dropnav-inner">
                        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropnav-links">
                            <li>
                                <h6>Desktops</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-one" title="Broadleaf">PC One</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-access" title="Broadleaf">PC Access</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc-max" title="Broadleaf">PC Max</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/pc" title="Flex">PC</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/desktops/all-in-one" title="All In One">All In One</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <h6>Workstations</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/pcx" title="Broadleaf X">PC X</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-rhino" title="D4 Rhino">D4 Rhino</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-3ds" title="D4 3DS">D4 3DS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/d4-inventor" title="D4 Inventor">D4 Inventor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/workstations/rackstation" title="Rackstation">Rackstations</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h6>On The Go</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/laptops" title="Laptop">Laptops</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/tablets" title="Tablet">Tablets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/products/onthego/ultrabooks" title="Ultrabook">Ultrabooks</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="showcase">
                            <div id="sc-inner"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kYkba/11/ link for any who can access this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout :)

**Edit**

You should also change

```
}).mouseout(function() {
```

to

```
}).on('mouseleave',function() {
```

Comment: I used to have that and changed to mouseover/mouseout to see if it would help, but alas it did not :( ty for the suggestion though.

Comment: OK I tested this out of curiosity and it works! thank you very much, I have no idea why it did not work yesterday when I used that combo.

Comment: you should also pay attention to this line }).mouseout(function() { and use .on(), like this: }).on('mouseleave',function() {

Comment: Ah, am correct in thinking that's called 'binding'? In my last comment, I forgot to mention I did not use `mouseeneter` with `.on` maybe that is why.

Comment: Yes you are, .on() is the new way to deal with event handler attachments

Answer (score 1):

See when you `mouseover` the li then it shows but when you go to select someitem in the `.dropnav` it `fadeOut`, instead try this:

```
var $target = $("header nav > ul > li");
$target.hover(function (e) {
   $('> .dropnav', this).slideDown();
},function () {
   $('> .dropnav', this).fadeOut();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kYkba/15/)

Comment: Going to try this and add in some of the code I have to allow for mouseout timeout recover etcetera.

Comment: I have gone with Robin's answer as his includes all my specific coding for usability. Thank you for your suggestion which also works.